# How do I capture the response of URL every-time new tab opens

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to develop a web-scraping project, in which I am scraping a website called Startup India, which you can use for connecting with startups. Here, I have clicked based on some filters I selected , and clicked on every startup and when I click on every startup, I have to go inside that startup and scrape it.  But I can't scrape the data because I'm not able to capture the response for scraping profiles in startup India.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import logging
class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.startupindia.gov.in/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.startupindia.gov.in/content/sih/en/search.html?industries=sih:industry/advertising&states=sih:location/india/andhra-pradesh&stages=Prototype&roles=Startup&page=0']

    def __init__(self):
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/RAJ/PycharmProjects/WebCrawler/WebCrawler/WebCrawler/spiders/chromedriver.exe")


    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)


        next = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='persona-results']//a[@class='img-wrap']")


        logging.info(next)

        for i in next:
            try:
                logging.info(i.click())
                logging.info(response.url)

                # get the data and write it to scrapy items
            except:
                print("Yolo")
```

Code will be appreciated

Comment: In Selenium you have the `current_url` method that can get the url of current window.

Comment: @dermouser123 I tried it won't work.

Comment: What params you passed to parse function?

Comment: @Yun I've passed self and response.

Comment: The data you are looking for is loaded with this API call: https://api.startupindia.gov.in/sih/api/noauth/search/profiles
I would make a request to this api referred from your start_url to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup scrapy project and run  `scrapy crawl product_spider` and it gives URL of new tab open after clicking on an element.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

CHROME_DRIVER_UBUNTU_PATH = "your chrome driver path"


class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.startupindia.gov.in/']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.startupindia.gov.in/content/sih/en/search.html?industries=sih:industry/advertising&states=sih:location/india/andhra-pradesh&stages=Prototype&roles=Startup&page=0']

    def __init__(self):
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        opts = ChromeOptions()
        opts.add_argument("--headless")  # for headless browser it's not necessary

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_UBUNTU_PATH, chrome_options=opts)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        next = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='persona-results']//a[@class='img-wrap']")

        for i in next:
            try:
                i.click()  # click on image in page
                # move to new tab open
                self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[next.index(i) + 1])
                logging.info(self.driver.current_url)

                self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])
                # get the data and write it to scrapy items
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```